# jQuery Mobile: Dynamically loaded content bloating the DOM

Tags: html, caching, dom, jquery-mobile

TLDR: Injecting and then replacing popup components into a div via AJAX is causing jQM to insert its own overlay elements outside of the div without removing them.

I have a jQM web page which dynamically loads the contents of a div tag on success of an ajax call:

```
$("#contentPane").html(data).trigger("create");
```

The ajax call can be made several times, each one replacing the previous contents of the div. The contents which are loaded vary: they may have identical components to what was previously there or, they may be completely different.

What I'm noticing is that if the contents I inject contain UI components which "popup" from the page (for example a dialog, or a selectmenu with `data-native-menu = "false"`) JQM inserts overlay elements directly into the body tag or the active page tag, outside my active page's main content div.

For example:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class="ui-page ui-body-b ui-page-header-fixed ui-page-active" position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-role="page">
        <div id="contentHeader" class="ui-header ui-bar-b ui-header-fixed slidedown" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-role="header" role="banner">...</div>
        <div id="contentPane" class="ui-content ui-body-b" data-theme="b" data-role="content" role="main">...</div>
        <div class="ui-selectmenu ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-body-a pop ui-selectmenu-hidden">...</div>
        <div class="ui-selectmenu-screen ui-screen-hidden"></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-dialog ui-overlay-a" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-role="dialog" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 399px;">
</body>
```

The problem is that whenever I replace the contents of my "contentPane" div, these overlay elements stay in the DOM. If the new contents I inject require overlay elements as well, JQM creates new ones without removing the stale ones. So eventually my DOM looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-page ui-body-b ui-page-header-fixed ui-page-active" position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-role="page">
    <div id="contentHeader" class="ui-header ui-bar-b ui-header-fixed slidedown" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-role="header" role="banner">...</div>
    <div id="contentPane" class="ui-content ui-body-b" data-theme="b" data-role="content" role="main">...</div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu-screen ui-screen-hidden" style="height: 3150px;"></div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-body-a pop ui-selectmenu-hidden">...</div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu-screen ui-screen-hidden"></div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu ui-selectmenu-hidden ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-body-a pop">...</div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu-screen ui-screen-hidden"></div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu ui-selectmenu-hidden ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-body-a pop">...</div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu-screen ui-screen-hidden"></div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu ui-selectmenu-hidden ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-body-a pop">...</div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu-screen ui-screen-hidden"></div>
    <div class="ui-selectmenu ui-selectmenu-hidden ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-body-a pop">...</div>
</div>
```

Now this isn't a HUGE issue, as it doesn't break any functionality, but seeing how this is a mobile app, bloating up the DOM can lead to slow performance  if it gets out of hand.

What I'm wondering is if there is some way I can tell JQM to clean up any of these stale DOM elements, or if there is a way I can check if any of these overlays have gone stale myself, say by using `$(".ui-overlay-shadow, .ui-overlay-a")` and then checking some property.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the elements you inject into your page into a variable then use the `.remove()` operator from jQuery, [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
var injectedDomElement = ...;
$(document).one("pagehide", function(){
    injectedDomElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't removing the overlay elements. The jQuery documentation does say that with .remove(), "all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed", but I guess the overlays created by JQM aren't "bound" per se to the elements that I injected.

Comment: So it doesn't remove the elements from the DOM? That is odd, because it shouldn't matter if jQM did anything with the elements or not. Maybe only for function binds but not for the DOM elements...

Comment: It's removing the elements I injected, just not the ones JQM created when it parsed through my elements. I can't really call `.remove()` on **all** elements in the page which match the overlay classes, as there may be some popups on the page which are completely unrelated to the elements I injected. That's why I was wondering if perhaps the overlays had some property to indicate that they have gone "stale".

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting to save your injected DOM element inside a variable so that you can target only those elements that you injected.

Comment: jQuery mobile parses my injected code and inserts new elements **outside** of where I injected mine. For example, I put my elements into a div tag which is inside the "ControlContent" tag in my example above, but JQM inserted its own divs (all the "ui-select-menu etc") outside of "ControlContent". So if I save my injected element into a variable and `.remove()` it, it wont affect the overlays because they aren't contained in my variable.